# Creating public instance of private inner class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Why Kotlin doesn't allow creation of public instances of private inner classes unlike Java?

Works in Java:

```
public class Test {
  public A a = new A();

  private class A {
  }
}
```

Doesn't work in Kotlin (`A` class has to be `public`):

```
class Test {
    var a = A()
//      ^  
// 'public' property exposes its private type 'A'

    private inner class A
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume because there isn't really a case where it seems like the right thing to do.  Any code accessing the property `a` would not have access to its type.  You couldn't assign it to a variable.  `Test.A myVar` declaration outside of the `Test` class would error out.  By not allowing it, the code will be forced to be more consistent.  A better question would be why would Java allow it? Other languages, such as swift, have the same restriction.

Answer (score 2):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces

states:

> NOTE for Java users: outer class does not see private members of its inner classes in Kotlin.

For your usecase, you can use [Nested Classes](http://NOTE%20for%20Java%20users:%20outer%20class%20does%20not%20see%20private%20members%20of%20its%20inner%20classes%20in%20Kotlin.)

In `private inner classes` you are only able to access members of your outer class.

I think the kotlin team implemented it that way, so that is possible to reduce the scope of members in `private inner classes` to be accessible only inside the `inner class`. I think this is not possible in Java.