# Public instance of private class - never allowable in c#

Tags: c#

Apparently this works in Java:

```
class BigClass
{
    public SecretClass not_so_secret = new SecretClass();

    public class SecretClass
    {
        // Methods and stuff
    }
}
```

But is there no equivalent in c#? Where I can create an instance of BigClass but NOT be allowed to create the subclass `SecretClass`:

```
class testing_class
{
    BigClass BIG_CLASS_SHOULD_BE_ALLOWED = new BigClass();
    BigClass.SecretClass SUB_CLASS_SHOULD_NOT = new BigClass.SecretClass();
}
```

I've tried combinations of internal (which sounded right...), private, protected - basically just all of them now :D

Is it a **fundamental** no-way-round principle in c# to always have this one-way street for access modifiers?

By the way I did find a sort-of answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923843/creating-public-instance-of-private-inner-class-in-kotlin) referring to Kotlin (whatever that is) and it seems to be a strict thing that just wouldn't make sense to some or be dangerous for some reason - public instances of an "internally" created private class

Is there no way to achieve that level of access in c#?

Comment: If you want to use the nested class publicly, then just make it public. Don't confuse nested and private! It can be nested **and** public. You could also make the class `sealed` for more protection.

Comment: If you're going to expose the class _publicily_ through a variable (instance), what the point of making it private in the first place?

Comment: The point is very minor but literally to cut down on possibilities for anyone using the class - I didn't want instances of the subclass to be created without having the parent class "controlling" it. It might be stupid but I wanted to understand if it was possible.

Comment: Then make its constructor private (and anything else that you want to keep secret).

Comment: They would still be able to do something like `BigClass.SecretClass.SomeProperty = "Got you!";`. You can't prevent them from editing the _public writable_ properties of the _already created_ instance. You can, however, have some private/internal or read-only members if you wish.

Comment: Click! Thanks Olivier. Makes sense. So I can have the class itself public and just control things via private methods in that class, controlled by the owning class. I swear I will get to grips with this one day.

Comment: You can also make the setter private: ` public string Text { get; private set; }`

Comment: I tried a `private` constructor which worked to stop instancing in other classes, but that meant I still couldn't actually create an instance within the owning class using `= new SecretClass()` - I think I can still achieve the level of control with private properties and public methods though, so thanks.

Comment: Don't confuse `private` with secret. Access levels are not about security.

Comment: No, secret was just a tenuous example, I know they don't have anything to do with security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a member (field, property, method, event, delegate or nested type) public, all the types exposed by this member must be public.

However, there is a trick on how you can make the class only instantiateable within `BigClass`: Make the class `abstract`, and if you need to write a constructor, make it  `protected` or, since C# 7.2 `private protected` (see below). Then derive a nested `private class` from it.

```
public class BigClass
{
    public SecretClass not_so_secret = new VerySecretClass();

    public abstract class SecretClass
    {
    }

    private class VerySecretClass : SecretClass
    {
    }
}
```

Also make everything private or protected that you don't need to expose. You can even give the setters more restrictive access modifiers.

```
public string Text { get; private set; } // or: protected set;
```

It also helps to make things `internal` if you are writing a class library. It makes things invisible for other assemblies.

---

Since C# 7.2 there is also a new level of accessibility (from [C# 7 Series, Part 5: Private Protected](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/10/05/c-7-series-part-5-private-protected/)):

> **Private Protected**
>
> Private Protected: The member declared with this accessibility can be visible within the types derived from this containing type within
> the containing assembly. It is not visible to any types not derived
> from the containing type, or outside of the containing assembly. i.e.,
> the access is limited to derived types within the containing assembly.

Comment: Now THAT'S clever - it's done it exactly - I knew there'd be a way... there's always a way. Now my `testing_class` above compiles fine on the first line and throws an error on the 2nd where it should. Fantastic!